# How to validate confirm password with password using regex in meteor

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor

I am Using meteor for developing my app. I need to validate my signup form so that it restrict the user. Now , I have password and confirm password in my signup form. I am using regex for the validation.

My code is :

```
Template.signup.rendered = function() {
    $("#signup").validate({
        rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            pattern:/^[A-Za-z ]{0,20}$/
        },
        age: {
          required: true,
          pattern:/^[0-9]{0,3}$/
        },
        disease: {
          required: true,
          pattern:/^[A-Za-z ]{0,30}$/
        },
        city: {
          required: true,
          pattern:/^[A-Za-z ]{0,20}$/
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          pattern:/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
        },
        pass: {
          required:true,
          pattern: /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*_]{6,20}$/
        },
        c_pass: {
          required:true,
          pattern: $("#pass").val();
        },
        messages: {
        name: {
        required: "Enter Name",
        pattern : "Only alphabets"
        },
        age:{
          required: "Enter age",
          pattern : "Only digits and length should be 2"
        },
        disease:{
          required: "This field is required",
          pattern : "Only alphabets"
        },
        city: {
          required: "This field is required",
          pattern : "Only alphabets allowed"
        },
        email: {
          required: "Please Enter an Email",
          pattern : "Please Enter a valid email address"
        },
        pass: {
          required: "Please enter password",
          pattern: "Password should be 6 or more"
        },
        c_pass: {
          required: "Enter Confirm Password",
          pattern: "Password does not match"
        }
    });
}
```

Now, I need some kind of code so that i can compare the confirm password and password inside rendered and using regex or something else.

Comment: Keep validation on `primary_password`, if its valid then simply just match `confirm_password` string with `primary_password` and you are done.

Comment: how can i match primary_pass with confirm_pass inside rendered?

Comment: use ```Template.signup.events``` with onChange attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend pure client side validation try using this package

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema